# JSON.parse: parse array in object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON string of an object that has an array as one of its properties. How can I get the resulting object to have an array of strings:

```js
let arr = ['10','22'];
let obj = `{
    "name":"bob",
    "arr":"${arr}"
}`;
let parse = JSON.parse(obj);
console.log(parse);
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "name":"bob",
    "arr":['10','22']
}
```

Comment: There isn't any array in your data. There some arbitrary text representation of an array in `arr`. It is not JSON.

Comment: Both properties are strings. If you expect an array for the property `arr`, use `["10", "20"]` instead of `"['10','20']"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `JSON.stringify` and remove two double-quotes `"`

```js
let arr = ["10", "22"]
let obj = `{
    "name":"bob",
    "arr":${JSON.stringify(arr)}
}`
let parse = JSON.parse(obj)
console.log(parse)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the definition. You are trying to include an array in the string. And if you try to print array as a string in JavaScript it joins the keys with `,`. To make it work, you need to convert the array as JSON string and remove the double-quotes, and it will work as expected.

```
let arr = ['10','22'];
let obj = `{
    "name":"bob",
    "arr": ${JSON.stringify(arr)}
}`;
let parse = JSON.parse(obj);
console.log(parse);
```